# Why JPype does return any result with gunicorn?

Tags: python, gunicorn, jpype

I run a flask web app that depends on java methods. The jpype + flask builtin web server works together, but jpype + gunicorn do not work.

```
gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:80 x.main:app --preload

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    ...
    result = self.java_class.java_method(args)
    ...
```

The result line does not return any results. So gunicorn throws timeout.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: could u share more info pls? it's a rest api so are u calling it with the correct method, which parameters are u passing? whats the actual API answer etc...

Comment: the problem is only jpype part. it works with flask web server but gunicorn

Answer (score 0):

This might be something to do with JPype not liking to work with forked processes, which is I think how Gunicorn works. I might try without the --prefork, and I might try somehow to start JPype after a gunicorn worker has started.